# Excel summing with multiple criteria in matrix

Tags: excel, matrix

First time user, so please excuse my noviceness...

I'm wondering which formula to apply in Excel when the aim is to sum figures in a matrix where there are multiple criterias.

Example matrix:
[Example matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dYjg.jpg)

Please see the above link for matrix.
I want to sum the cells with "2017" and "a" as criteria in one single cell (hence the result should be 76 (15+16+15+30)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us what your criteria cell looks like plz, e.g. 2017a or 2017,a etc.

Comment: Critera cells are also a matrix with colums to be years (2017-2021) and rows the letters "a" trough "c"

Comment: Ah OK that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

If your original data is in B2:E4 with headers in the first row and column, and your criteria in H2:L2 with headers in the first row and column G, it should be

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$E$4*($B$1:$E$1=H$1)*($A$2:$A$4=$G2))
```

starting in H2 and pulled across and down.

[image]